# No executable found matching command "dotnet-script"

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dotnet-tool

Why doesn't `dotnet script` run in PowerShell after installation? I closed and reopened all PowerShell instances after installing.

PowerShell throws this error when I run `dotnet script init`:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-script"

**Edit:**

- `dotnet script` does run in `cmd.exe`
- The `dotnet` and `.dotnet\tools` folders are present in `PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by:

1. **Removing old PATH entries** in case PATH was too large ([source](https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script/issues/303#issuecomment-393927574))
2. **Restarting the computer** because PowerShell's `$env:PATH` wasn't updating even after closing/reopening all PowerShell instances ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547075/1958726))

Answer (score 2):

While I'm sure that [your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53601592/45375) helped, it's worth digging deeper:

> The `dotnet` and `.dotnet\tools` folders are present in PATH

To produce your symptom, the former must be true, but not the latter:

It is `dotnet.exe` that issues the error message (implying that `dotnet.exe` itself indeed *is* in the PATH).

The error message indicates that a tool named `script` could not be located, implying that an executable named `dotnet-script.exe` could not be found in the PATH, because that's the executable name that `dotnet` constructs behind the scenes when you call `dotnet script`.

With a properly set up PATH (and, of course, [dotnet-script](https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script) installed), `dotnet-script.exe` should be found via the `$HOME\.dotnet\tools` directory in the PATH.

`$HOME\.dotnet\tools` is an entry stored as part of the user-specific PATH additions in the registry, and your PowerShell session seemingly hadn't picked up that entry yet - which can happen for the reasons mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the folder containing `dotnet` is not in your PATH environment variable. Add it to that variable.

Also note that dotnet will install in *two* locations if you install both x86 and x64 versions, and will only ever pick one if both end up in PATH. This can lead to very strange results when updating!

Comment: This is likely the cause. Here is a link to show how to add it to PATH: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5148

Comment: I should have clarified that this is specific to PowerShell. `dotnet` and `.dotnet\tools` are present in `PATH` and `dotnet script` works in `cmd.exe`. Question edited.

Comment: That can't be the cause, because the error message in the question is _issued_ by `dotnet.exe` implying that `dotnet` itself is indeed in the PATH. Note how the error message complains about `dotnet-script`, not `dotnet`.